# Maven Modules assembly/shade build

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the following module structure:

```
powercontrol
    powercontrol-core
        pom.xml
    powercontrol-data
        pom.xml
    powercontrol-gui
        pom.xml
    powercontrol-ui
        pom.xml
pom.xml
```

Now I want that the GUI (Graphical User Interface) and UI (Command Line User Interface) can be executed by the client.
I tried to use the maven shade plugin inside the GUI and UI, but this makes it really a mess.

I prefer:

- A jar file with all the third party dependencies (log4j etc).
- A jar file (or maybe lib folder?) with all the project modules.
- A'n executor for the GUI and UI.

*Example:*

```
powercontrol/
    bin/
        gui
        ui
    lib/
        third-party.jar
        powercontrol-core.jar
        powercontrol-data.jar
        powercontrol-gui.jar
        powercontrol-ui.jar
```

I'm a bit stuck with getting a good structure now, where should I start?

All feedback, suggestions etc are welcome. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE 8/28/2015**

I made a new module named: **powercontrol-dist** that will be executed as last in the Maven lifecycle. This module will generate a lib folder and copy all the dependencies from the powercontrol-gui and powercontrol-cli to this folder.

Now I have 2 questions!

**Question 1**

Is this a good way to go? Or is there a better way?

*powercontrol-dist/pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.nberlijn.powercontrol</groupId>
        <artifactId>powercontrol</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>powercontrol-dist</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>PowerControl Dist</name>
    <description>Dist</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>powercontrol-gui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>powercontrol-cli</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*Output:*

```
powercontrol/
    bin/
        gui.exe
        ui.exe
    lib/
        third-party-lib.....jar
        third-party-lib.....jar
        third-party-lib.....jar
        powercontrol-core.jar
        powercontrol-data.jar
        powercontrol-gui.jar
        powercontrol-cli.jar
```

**Question 2**

Also I want to make two .exe files "gui.exe and cli.exe" referencing to the powercontrol-gui.jar and the powercontrol-cli.jar.

Is adding a mainclass to the manifest inside the pom.xml in the powercontrol-gui and powercontrol-cli module enough?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How do you expect to invoke your "executor" JARs?

Comment: "A jar file with all the third party dependencies (log4j etc).". That's exactly what `maven-shade-plugin` does. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Tunaki That's 100% true! But the point is that I'm stuck to get the job done :-(

Comment: @rec An excutable jar (gui.jar, ui.jar) will be fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you want two executable JARs (gui.jar, ui.jar), you should add the shade plugin to those two modules, so that as part of each module, a standalone executable JAR is built. Both of the JARs will contain all the third-party stuff as well. You cannot create a standalone executable JAR where parts of the dependencies are in an external JAR (unless you do you own classloader magic or unless you also have to specify the external JAR on the command line).

If you are stuck with the maven shade plugin, you should tell us what problem exactly you have. Typically these can be resolved. A common problem is that certain files need to be "merged" when a shaded JAR is created, in particular files in META-INF e.g. used by Spring or by the Java Service Locator mechanism. The shade plugin offers support for such merging, but it needs to be configured for the case at hand.

Btw. I'd recommend calling the command line version "cli.jar" - "ui" sounds like "gui".

---

Ok, since you updated your question and now seem to be asking for a "native launcher" (exe file) instead of an executable JAR file - those are completely different things.

Launching an exe file from the command line:

```
C:\> gui
```

Launching an executable JAR file from the command line

```
C:\ java -jar gui.jar
```

To get the first, you need to create a native launcher that internally invokes Java. A project that might support you in that task could be [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net) - they also seem to provide a Maven plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice! I renamed the ui into cli. Also I updated my question where I explain my question(s) better now.

Comment: Thanks, this is where I was looking for! If I have no executable JAR files, is adding the manifest info to the GUI and CLI pom.xml enough? (ref. Question 2)

Comment: The mainClass in the manifest is typically used by executable JAR files. If you use another mechanism such as launch4j, you need to read in their documentation if they make use of the manifest or if they rely on some other mechanism.

Comment: Thanks again, I will take a look into that and update my post when I know more! So it can helps other people out with the same question.